# How to get the group in DataTable multi-level grouping for styling the group row?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using the DataTable multi-level grouping as described [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/examples/initialisation/multipleGroups.html). Everything works fine. But I want to style the group heading row such that group heading should appear in the corresponding column. Currently, it is displayed as below

[image]

I want it like below

[image]

I know there is a call back function to display the row. But how can I identify which group the row represents?

```
rowGroup: {
                startRender: function(rows, group) {
                    return $('<tr/>')
                    .append( '<td colspan="3">'+group+'</td>' )
                    .append( '<td></td>' )
                    .append( '<td/>' )
                    .append( '<td></td>' )
                    .append( '<td></td>' )
                    .append( '<td></td>' );
                },
                dataSrc: [1, 2]
            },
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to identify the group by using below code.

```
rowGroup: {
                startRender: function(rows, group) {
                    if (rows.data().pluck(1)[0] == group) {
                        return $('<tr/>')
                            .append('<td>' + group + '</td>')
                            .append('<td></td>')
                            .append('<td/>')
                            .append('<td></td>')
                            .append('<td>' + rows.data().pluck(5)[0] + '</td>')
                            .append('<td></td>');
                    } else if (rows.data().pluck(2)[0] == group) {
                        return $('<tr/>')
                            .append('<td></td>')
                            .append('<td>' + group + '</td>')
                            .append('<td/>')
                            .append('<td></td>')
                            .append('<td></td>')
                            .append('<td></td>');
                    }
                },
                dataSrc: [1, 2]
            },
```